# Azure API Management Policy- "rewrite-url" policy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I am trying to create a policy, that will pull the insurer ID out of the input body and put it in the URL as shown in the picture below.
Trying to clean up request body and reconstruct URL so the request can successfuly post to our approve endpoint

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

[https://apimanagement.test.com/consto-123/api/relationship/approve/{id}](https://apimanagement.test.com/consto-123/api/relationship/approve/%7Bid%7D)

Request body:

```json
{
    "insurer_name": "Tony",
    "insurer_id": "12345",
    "comments": "This is test"
}
```

Comment: This will not work. The request is a combination of URL and Body at the same time. You can go back and change the initial request URL.  You have extract the `insurer_id` from body and pass it to your backend -> https://mybackend.com/api/relationship/approve{insurer_id}

Comment: Alright thank you for getting back to me. I may have not explained it well. But is there a way you can show, what you have described above. I think what you have explained, is what I am trying to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the `insurer_id` from the request-body and store it as a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#set-variable):

```xml
<set-variable name="insurerId" value="@{
    var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
    return body["insurer_id"].Value<string>();
}" />
```

Afterwards you can use [rewrite-uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) with this variable and forward the request to the blackened.

The complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="insurerId" value="@{
            var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
            return body["insurer_id"].Value<string>();
        }" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/api/relationship/approve/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("insurerId"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```